# String Matching in R like PRXMATCH() in SAS

Tags: r, sas, text-analysis

Seeking your help to understand how to match strings in `R`, like `PRXMATCH()` does in `SAS`.

```
List1 <-c("lead","good")
List2 <-c("Quality","understand")
Name  <-c("grp1","grp2")
```

I have a dataframe containing column `sentence`. For every sentence I need to:

- Look for words in `List1`
- If word is found then corresponding word of `List2` is looked for.
- If word is found  at +-5 words distance from the word from `List1`, then the name from `Name` should be added to the `result` column.

For example, `"lead"` is searched for in all sentences. When `"lead"` is found,  then within that sentence, if `"Quality"` is found at +-5 words distance then `"grp1"` should be added in the `result` column, else discarded.

Comment: Consider making a small reproducible example. If you're looking for a tool that will detect if a word is within a string `grepl` may be for you.

Comment: You don't need to _implement_ `PRXMATCH` -- you just need to find the equivalent function(s) in `R`. `grepl` seems adequate in this case. As for your description of the problem, you're more likely to have an answer if you make clear, bullet-point rules, provide a short sample of your source data (sentences), and what your desired output objects should look like, after applying those rules.

Comment: I've edited the question, please check that it does correspond to what you are after.

Comment: @DominicComtois thank you for the quick response. I tried grepl function but problem is i want to search second word in proximity of first word. I.e. I am using following code ifelse(grepl("lead.*quality|quality.*lead",sentence),"grp1","discard") but here i want when first word lead is found then second word quality to be searched in vincinity of 5 words of lead..here i am facing challenge that what pattern to be used to get second word searched in vicinity of +- 5 words of first word...Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
myData <- data.frame(sentence = c("The quality bla bla bla lead bla", 
                                  "The quality bla bla bla bla bla lead bla",
                                  "The lead quality bla bla",
                                  "The lead bla bla quality",
                                  "The lead bla bla bla bla bla quality of",
                                  "It allows us to understand how good bla",
                                  "It is good to understand that bla",
                                  "It is also good bla bla bla if we understand",
                                  "lead quality is good to understand"),
                     Result = "",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

List1 <-c("lead","good")
List2 <-c("quality","understand")
Name  <-c("grp1","grp2")

regexpr <- paste0("(\\b",List1,"\\s+(\\w+\\s+){0,4}",List2,"\\b)|(\\b",List2,"\\s+(\\w+\\s+){0,4}",List1,"\\b)")


for(i in 1:length(regexpr)) {
  myData$Result <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = regexpr[i], x = myData$sentence), 
                          yes = paste(myData$Result, Name[i]), 
                          no = myData$Result)
}
```

### Results

```
> myData
                                      sentence     Result
1             The quality bla bla bla lead bla       grp1
2     The quality bla bla bla bla bla lead bla           
3                     The lead quality bla bla       grp1
4                     The lead bla bla quality       grp1
5      The lead bla bla bla bla bla quality of           
6      It allows us to understand how good bla       grp2
7            It is good to understand that bla       grp2
8 It is also good bla bla bla if we understand           
9           lead quality is good to understand  grp1 grp2
```

Comment: Awesome Dominic... You are super hero... Thanks a ton for the quick help..it will be very helpfull if you could explain me regexpr <- paste0("(\\b",List1,"\\s+(\\w+\\s+){0,4}",List2,"\\b)|(\\b",List2,"\\s+(\\w+\\s+){0,4}",List1,"\\b)")
 along with for loop... i struggled in understanding this pattern matching... thanks again for your time and support!!

Comment: For the regular expression symbols, I refer you to the help for `regex` (type `?regex` to get there). But briefly, \\b means word boundary, \\s means blank character, and \\w means word characters. As for the loop, in just has 2 iterations since you have only two sets of words/names, but you could add some in and the code as it is would take them into account, thanks to the way `paste` handles vectors. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem for you! :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response... please tell me how i can accept the answer... I am new here not sure abt this step..

Comment: If possible please help with this query as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560084/sentence-theme-classification-using-r